# Use a designed function second time after I made some modification

Tags: python, function

I previously designed a function called show_city to print the image of a 2D array.
At the beginning, I used the function to print the initial city, and later I called another function to make some adjustment to my data. And print out the city one more time. But I lost the first image I printed. I wondered if there is anything I can do to keep them both.

```
show_city(board)
startRumor(board)


show_city(board)
```

I attached my show_city function below:

```
def show_city(board):
    plt.imshow(board)
    plt.axis('off')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plt.savefig() to save the image.  See the example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#make board
dx, dy = 0.1, 0.1
y, x = np.mgrid[slice(-4, 4 + dy, dy),slice(-4, 4 + dx, dx)]
z = x**2 + y**2

def show_city(board):
    plt.imshow(board)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig('saved.png')
    plt.show()

show_city(z)
```

This is the saved.png:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To draw a new figure, call [`plt.figure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) before calling `imshow`.